# Select text from div - the not obvious way

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my div :

```
<div id="myDiv">The 
<span class="cordial-err-corr" id="good0-0" data-original-title="" title="">best</span>
 way to receive congrats 
<span>
  <span class="cordial-err-corr" id="good0-1" data-original-title="" title="">are</span>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="prop0-1">is</a></li>
        <li><a class="prop0-1">are</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</span> to give a correct answer.</div>
```

I would like to get this text : *"The best way to receive congrats are to give a correct answer."*

So I call `$('#myDiv').text()`. It does not work since I get the two elements in `ul.dropdown-menu`.

The next step is to filter or remove the un-wanted children, i.e.:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="prop0-1">is</a></li>
    <li><a class="prop0-1">are</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to play with $.filter or $.not or $.children with jquery selectors, etc. I cannot find the correct way to do this. Need help!

You can find some code in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7FY/

**[EDIT]**
One solution suggests this code :

```
$('#result').append( $('#myDiv').text().replace($(".btn-group").text(),"") ).append('<br />')
```

If several `div.btn-group` exists, just loop as :

```
var result = $('#myDiv').text();
$(".btn-group").each(function() {
    result = result.replace($(this).text(),"");
});
$('#result').append(result).append('<br />')
```

Comment: regex to extract characters of div.text()?

Comment: well first you have to distinguish which li is the correct one, than you can continue to filter

Comment: If by "right" one you mean the selected one, you could try something with jQuery's `:selected` selector : http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7FY/3/ but you need to change jQuery version. Since we know version needs to be newer, some other person here can tell us maybe why 1.7.2 doesn't work

Comment: Why are you using list instead of a `<select>` element?

Comment: In your jsfiddle you cannot choose between the two options in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you folks! I'll answer to all of you.

Comment: @dirt I did not understand if you asked a question or if you suggesting a solution.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev
@Alex
@CD001
This code extract is built with bootstrap. The selected element is already choosen in then `span.cordial-err-corr#good0-1`. So what I need is to zap everything under `div.btn-group` (see accepted answer below)

Comment: @Yeronimo Hug! I use 1.9.1 in my project, but in jsfiddle, I needed bootstrap api, so I was forced to set the jquery version to 1.7.2 (I do not know how to do otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I get this straight, you want to exclude the list from the `.text()`. Try something like:

```
$('#result').append( $('#myDiv').text().replace($(".dropdown-menu").text(),"") ).append('<br />')
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess this is the cleanest solution. see http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7FY/8/

Comment: I uncheck your solution as accepted because I need a little bit more help, see edit in my question.

Comment: Ok, Monday is not the best day to think... `$(".dropdown-menu").text()` returns all text in one, so replace never found this concatened text. So I would add a loop.

Comment: But what about if there are some other text as the same as the text returned by $(".dropdownn-menu").text()?

Comment: @pktangyue Yes, I thought about this when I was implementing it. But we can validate that if the first word is A and the suggestion is B, we will have AAB or BAB. So... It is a thin heuristic but I implemented this.

Comment: OK then did you manage to get it working, or do you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function process(el){
    var array = [];
    $(el).contents().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), text;
        if(this.nodeType == 3){
            text = $.trim($this.text());
            if(text){
                array.push(text)
            }
        } else if($this.is(':not(.btn-group)')){
            Array.prototype.push.apply(array, process(this))
        }
    })
    return array;
}

console.log(process($('#myDiv')).join(' '))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QE5Kv/5/)

Comment: Your solution is to complex, to long. Andrei Nemes was able to find a one line solution. See http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7FY/8/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind placing all the "dumb" text in spans, then you can do it very simply by only grabbing "dumb" text spans and ".cordial-err-corr" spans (and a `find()`).

```
<div class="well" id="myDiv"><span class="cordial-content">The </span> 
<span class="cordial-err-corr" id="good0-0" data-original-title="" title="">best </span>
 <span class="cordial-content">way to receive congrats  </span>
<span>
  <span class="cordial-err-corr" id="good0-1" data-original-title="" title="">are </span>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="prop0-1">is</a></li>
        <li><a class="prop0-1">are</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</span> <span class="cordial-content">to give a correct answer. </span></div>
```

and

```
$('#myDiv').find('.cordial-err-corr,.cordial-content').text()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNKTf/1/)

Comment: Your solution is fine but does not work with the original html code as shown in the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7FY/8/

Answer (score 1):

I have an ugly, though simple enough (I guess) method:

We can make a copy, then remove the dom elements we don't want to display. Then we can get the desired text.

```
var clone_div = $('#myDiv').clone();
clone_div.find('.btn-group').remove();
$('#result').append(clone_div.text()).append('<br />');
```

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Ku7FY/4/

Comment: I thought about this solution, ugly but working ;) Thank you. I'll check the others.